# Type error when attempting to insert dict values into postgresql table

Tags: python, dictionary, psycopg2

I am having trouble inserting multiple values into a postgres table with python's psycopg2 executemany() function.  I have a dict with the following values:

```
{u'city': u'14000', u'sitename': u'12298', u'longitude': u'-9767764.18643674', u'county': u'17031', u'sourceid': u'42', u'state': u'17', u'latitude': u'5147311.10876352', u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': u'WY7EBHl55TuWSwXv4C3vNa5X5d0peJyv', u'sourcesiteid': u'42'  }
```

which I am attempting to insert with the following code:

```
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(db_connect)
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO cacw_sites(sourceid,sitename,sourcesiteid,state,county,city,schooldistrict,zipcode,neighborhood,latitude,longitude) 
                       VALUES ( %(sourceid)s, %(sitename)s, %(sourcesiteid)s, %(state)s, %(county)s, %(city)s, %(zipcode)s, %(neighborhood)s, 
                                %(latitude)s, %(longitude)s)""", dict)
    con.commit()
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'There was a problem updating the sites: %s'%e

finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

However, I keep receiving the error: **TypeError: string indices must be integers**

I realize that I am somehow trying to reference a string with another string but I am not sure  where.  If I do

```
dict['state']
```

I recieve the proper output of

```
u'17'
```

So how come I cannot seem  to insert these values correctly?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: try: `cur.executemany(..., [dict])`. `executemany` expects a list of lists or dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `executemany()` which expects a *sequence* of dictionaries, but give it just a dictionary.

Use:

```
cur.execute(
    """INSERT INTO cacw_sites(sourceid,sitename,sourcesiteid,state,county,city,schooldistrict,zipcode,neighborhood,latitude,longitude) 
       VALUES ( %(sourceid)s, %(sitename)s, %(sourcesiteid)s, %(state)s, %(county)s, %(city)s, %(zipcode)s, %(neighborhood)s, 
                %(latitude)s, %(longitude)s)""", dict)
```

instead.

What happens instead is that the database adapter loops over the dictionary object, which yields keys (each a string), then tries to find your parameters on those strings. You end up trying to do the equivalent of `'sourceid'['sourceid']` that way.